# How to refuse a response intentionally from Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am building an ASP.NET webapi restful service that responds to POSTed webhooks coming in from a third party integration partner.  That third party has implemented a signing mechanism I can use to verify that the request comes from them and is not a replay attack.  The third-party suggests as a best practice that if the signature is bad or if the timestamp is wrong, that I do not respond.  At all.  No error, no status, nothing.  I realize that I don't know how to do this.  My controller action determines that the request is bad, but how do I instruct the framework to NOT respond in this case?  To intentionally leave the perceived bad actor hanging?

Comment: What a weird recommendation. Most likely your server has already responded by the time you're able to check the signature (e.g. it has to respond to the TLS handshake just to establish the secure connection). Anyway, to halt the response, use `Reponse.Clear()` followed by [`Response.End()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end?view=netframework-4.8). Bear in the mind the client may receive a response anyway, e.g. from a proxy server in between, serving a 502 error.

Comment: You may want to add a small `await Task.Delay(1000)` before giving the empty response as suggested above. This would slow down brute force attacks against an API key for example. My concern is that whatever you come up with, if the solution holds up resources, you could make it easier for the bad actor to perform a denial of service attack against you.

Comment: Thanks @JohnWu - that looks good.  In your opinion, what should the controller action return?  Simply null?

Comment: Thanks @MikaelSuokas - that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Hopefully there's a great answer. Wrt @MikaelSuokas comment, it might be OK for this to do exponential back-off, but to some limit so you're not using up resources for too long of a time locally. I think answering this question means knowing a bit more about the proxies between parties though, and how they can or do respond.

Comment: @StephanG If the third party uses an authentication method in the [list of of authentication schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml), I'd suggest that you should be returning a 401 unauthorized status with a suitable WWW-Authenticate header field. Otherwise, a 403 forbidden should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the original question, here is the solution I have decided on for now.  Note that it does NOT leave the perceived bad actor hanging, but instead responds with an error that can be set in the config file or defaults to 404 NOT FOUND.  As far as I can tell, even with Response.Clear() and Response.End(), webapi will send an empty 200 response.  So I can't completely adhere to the suggestion of the third party.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using IntegrationResearch.Extension;

namespace IntegrationResearch.Filters
{
    public class VerificationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);

            IList<string> validationErrors = await actionContext.Request.GetSignedRequestVerificationErrorsAsync();  //The code that does the work of checking signed request

            if ((validationErrors?.Count ?? 0) != 0)
            {
                // TODO SG - definitely need to log the issue either way

                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
                    ? new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(string.Join(", ", validationErrors)) }
                    : new HttpResponseMessage(await GetDelayedVerificationFailureStatusCodeAsync()));
            }
        }

        private static async Task<HttpStatusCode> GetDelayedVerificationFailureStatusCodeAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[VerificationFailureDelayMillisecondsConfigKey], out int delayMilliseconds) ? delayMilliseconds : 1000);

            try
            {
                return (HttpStatusCode) int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[VerificationFailureStatusCodeConfigKey]);
            }
            catch
            {
                return HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            }
        }

        private const string VerificationFailureStatusCodeConfigKey = "VerificationFailureStatusCode";
        private const string VerificationFailureDelayMillisecondsConfigKey = "VerificationFailureDelayMilliseconds";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though it may make debugging from a browser easier, I don't like that with IsDebuggingEnabled you return 200 OK. I think you always should return 400 or 403 when verification fails. To see the error message you may have to tweak browser settings or use another tool such as Postman, Advanced REST Client or RESTer.

Comment: Thanks @MikaelSuokas - I hear you.  But in my case, I am dealing with a 3rd party that will only output the debugging info I want to see if the response has status 200.  Any other status will cause a simple "Request Failed" message.

I could of course instead check for a specific AppSetting in the config file that I designate for this purpose, and hearing your warning, that might be better....